# A RESTfull search service Question

Tags: c#, rest

I have a SQL Server (2008) database that contains address details that i want to make available to search as a rest service.

All that needs to be available is the ability to pass an address or part of an address and the service will return the potential candidates, much like yahoo or googles rest services.

My question is, from a high level what is the best approach to take for this?
I am using .net 4 and VS2010 but i have never made a rest service before.

Any links to similar articles or advice on the best approach would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've included a link to a very basic tutorial on making your own restful web service. Publishing web services aren't that difficult especially when no authentication is involved. Essentially you need to define a new class that inherits `IHttpHandler` interface, implement a couple of methods including the `ProcessRequest` inside which you can write text into the `Response` object. You may have to look into the `Request` object for query parameters (if you need to) and query your db accordingly.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RestServicesInASPNET2.aspx